# Totally locked out of MySQL

Tags: mysql, ubuntu

I've locked myself out of both the mysql root user and my main mysql user. Sudo Mysqladmin does nothing.

I'm using Mysql Version 8.0.29 and I'm using Ubuntu 20.04.4. A password is enabled for both root users and I've forgotten the password.

How can I use Mysql again?

Comment: Removed tags since your problem is unrelated to them, but worth pointing out that [Sqoop is an abandoned Apache project](https://sqoop.apache.org/)

Comment: Have you read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/resetting-permissions.html